# Gradient dynamical systems have no nonconstant recurrent solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

This is given as something we should intuitively understand, but I don't see how this is trivial.  We were given that a solution is recurrent if $X(t_n) \to X(0)$ for some sequence from $t_n$ to infinity.  Why is this true?

Comment: Just to mention why this should be "intuitive": If $f$ is the function whose gradient we are considering, and $X(t)$ follows $\nabla f$, then $f(X(t))$ should be increasing for all $t$ since the gradient points in the direction of steepest ascent for $f$.

Comment: Hint: if $X(t_n) \rightarrow X(0)$, what happens to $f(X(t_n))$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the gradient function $\Phi = \Phi({\bf x})$,

$$
\frac{{\rm d}{\bf x}}{{\rm d}t} = -\nabla \Phi \tag{1}
$$

Assume the system is recurrent

$$
\Phi({\bf x}(t_n)) = \Phi({\bf x}(0)) \tag{2}
$$

But on the other hand

$$
0 \stackrel{(2)}{=}\int {\rm d}\Phi = \int_0^{t_n} \nabla \Phi \cdot \frac{{\rm d}{\bf x}}{{\rm d}t} {\rm d}t \stackrel{(1)}{=} -\int_0^{t_n} \left| \frac{{\rm d}{\bf x}}{{\rm d }t}\right|^2{\rm d}t < 0
$$

So you get to a contradiction. A gradient dynamical system cannot have recurrent orbits!

Comment: Just a note: OP's question mentions "recurrent" trajectories which are more general than periodic orbits

Comment: How was the equation at the bottom arrived at, I am confused at the part with the (2) on top

Comment: @Bobert Over a closed orbit 

$$
\int_0^{t_n} {\rm d}\Phi = \Phi({\bf x}(t_n)) - \Phi({\bf x}(0)) \stackrel{(2)}{=} 0
$$